# Is there a standard way to transform a pose between coordinate frames?

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a pose message that I want to transform between two (non-static) coordinate frames. Currently I am doing the following in python:

```
   def rotate_orientation(ori, q):
    rot_mat = tf.transformations.quaternion_matrix(q)
    pose_rot = rot_mat.dot([ori.x, ori.y, ori.z, ori.w])
    ori.x = pose_rot[0]
    ori.y = pose_rot[1]
    ori.z = pose_rot[2]
    ori.w = pose_rot[3]

  def translate_position(pos, t):
    pos.x += t[0]
    pos.y += t[1]
    pos.z += t[2]

  def odom_to_utm(odom):
    global utm_pub

    trans,rot = listener.lookupTransform('utm', 'odom', rospy.Time(0))

    translate_position(odom.pose.pose.position, trans)
    rotate_orientation(odom.pose.pose.orientation, rot)

    utm_pub.publish(utm)
```

But it feels a bit clunky. Is there a more standard way to switch between coordinates frames? Something like a `tf.transformPose(pose, frame1, frame2)` that returns `pose` in frame 2.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267403/is-there-a-standard-way-to-transform-a-pose-between-coordinate-frames?/) by [linusnie](https://answers.ros.org/users/30863/linusnie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 98 on 2017-07-26

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is something like that, and you almost guessed it!

```
listener.transformPose(target_frame, pose_msg) -> pose_msg
```

You don't need to enter the frame1 because it is listed inside the pose_msg.

You can find more information [here](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/TfUsingPython#TransformerROS_and_TransformListener). And [here](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/tf/html/python/tf_python.html#tf.TransformerROS.transformPose) is the function in the API.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2017-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-26**:
Are you using `->` to say that function returns `pose_msg`?

**Comment by [linusnie](https://answers.ros.org/users/30863/linusnie/) on 2017-07-26**:
thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2017-07-26**:
Yes, it returns a new pose_msg